# Iscroll mousewheel scrolling works slow in firefox than Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll

**Please check this example link:** http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/demos/probe/

If i run above example page in chrome and scroll through mousewheel, the page goes up by 100px every time. You can see there is Y position printed. If i run same above page in firefox 26.0 and scroll through mousewheel, the page goes up by 3px every time. You can see that page goes up very slow in firefox. Is there any way to fix them?

Comment: As you are using a javascript to scroll I think the problem lies within your javascript

Comment: I am usigng iscroll v5.0 plugin for stylish scroll. iscroll v4.0 working fine in both browser.

Comment: I saw this: function updatePosition () {
position.innerHTML = this.y>>0;
}
`>>` should be `>` which might be problem

Comment: Please try by mousewheel scrolling in firefox. It scrolls very slow. I don't know why?

Comment: wheel value for delta is implemented per browser and OS very different ways, some of them are event reversed, some are accelerated, it all depends on the platform unfortunately. This is one of the examples of what is happening when some "standard" is not there in W3C, and all vendors do whatever they want, so inconsistency comes here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with the iscrolljs library, as reported 8 days ago on the github site for iscroll. Please refer to: https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/577

If you debug the code on Firefox you will see that deltaY is being adjusted only by -3 each time a scroll event occurs. This is different to chrome which has a very large deltaY adjustment on scroll.

I would suggest waiting until a patch is supplied. If your need is urgent then I would recommend using the older version until a fix is available.

Answer (score 2):

As I didn't have the option of reverting to an older version, I looked through the GitHub issue mentioned by Metalskin and I saw a temporary fix by a poster called 'justnorris'.

He modified the `_wheel` method in the `iscroll-probe.js` file directly at lines 1055 - 1057, with the following:

```
    if ( 'deltaX' in e ) {
        var multiply = ( e.deltaMode === 1 ) ? this.options.mouseWheelSpeed : 1;
        wheelDeltaX = -e.deltaX * multiply;
        wheelDeltaY = -e.deltaY * multiply;
    }
```

Source: https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/577#issuecomment-33715370

Do a `Ctrl+F5` (cache clear) of your page in Firefox and it should scroll fine now.

Note: This is a temporary working fix. Works for me as of today, on Firefox 27.0.1, Windows 8.